# Approximate irrational number using convergents of continued fractions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me with this problem:

> Among the convergents of $\sqrt{15}$, find a rational number that approximates $\sqrt{15}$ with accuracy to four decimal places.

I know how to find the continued fraction and the convergents for $\sqrt{15}$. But I am just not sure how to determine how far I need to go in order to approximate that number with the requested accuracy.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with a certain bound on the absolute value of the difference between a number $\alpha$ and one of its convergents?

Comment: $|\alpha - p_{n}/q_{n}| \le |\alpha -a/b|<1/2b^2$ ?

Comment: Of course, the lowbrow way to do this is to calculate $\sqrt{15}$ to 4 decimals, then calculate convergents to 4 decimals until you find one that works.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did at first, but something tells that the author had something else in mind.

Comment: @Daniel: yes, that one. Can you see how that answers your question?

Comment: @Qiaochu: yes, I think I know how to use that one. I was hoping to get a values for n, but I guess that not possible. Thanks for your help.